# Password format issue during Umbraco to Gigya full profile import

Tags: hmacsha1, gigya

I am doing profile import from Umbraco to Gigya (full account not lite account). I followed Gigya documentation and was able to complete the import, but post import i am not able to log in to the website using the imported email id and password. Let me explain the problem in detail:

I understood from client that in this case Ubmraco used HMACSHA1 as hashing algorithm and the password is used along with the same password as the key :

```
HMACSHA1 hash = new HMACSHA1();
hash.Key = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
encodedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password)));
```

https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/v8/contrib/src/Umbraco.Core/Security/MembershipProviderBase.cs#L903

I exported one of Gigya profiles (profile of a user who had registered through website, not imported profiles) from our test site and observed that Gigya by default uses the following settings:

```
{"hash":"UpPjLTDdSa4i+HNnWApBvW89f0U=","hashSettings":{"algorithm":"pbkdf2","rounds":3000,"salt":"a6lD095hHO/u2ZrQa/UpMux1Tho="}}
```

In the JSON file of import profile I used hash algorithm as pbkdf2 and in another scenario as SHA1 and tried profile import to Gigya. I tried password with salt, without salt i.e, multiple combinations, but nothing has helped so far.

```
 "password": {
      "hashedPassword": "a6lD095hHO/u2ZrQa/UpMux1Tho=",
      "hashSettings": {
        "algorithm": "pbkdf2",
        "salt": "a6lD095hHO/u2ZrQa/UpMux1Tho=",
        "rounds": "3000"
```

if the password is 'xyz', HMACSHA1 hash is a6lD095hHO/u2ZrQa/UpMux1Tho==, if is password is 'abc' HMACSHA1 hash is which is UpPjLTDdSa4i+HNnWApBvW89f0U=, and that is as per the following code :

```
HMACSHA1 hash = new HMACSHA1();
hash.Key = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
encodedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password)));
```

Gigya doesnt seem to support HMACSHA1 (as per the documentation https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/accounts.importFullAccount+REST). In my small POC (code snapshot provided below), when i debugged i saw that the HashName for HMACSHA1 is SHA1 and that's the reason i tried SHA1 as one of the algorithm to import profile into Gigya, even through client used HMACSHA1 for hashing. If you have done something similar please guide me.

Snapshot from Visual Studio Code